# copy a char array to an element of an array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have been writing a function for extract information between each two newline characters.I am facing a problem when copying the char array 'data' to an element of 'info' array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void query_db();

char buffer[100]="+HTTPREAD:86\nUdara\nNO\n+94123456789\nOK";
volatile int buffer_pointer;
char info[3][20];

int main()
{
    query_db();
    return 0;
}

void query_db(){
    unsigned char j=0,start,end,amount;
    char data[20];
    buffer_pointer = 0;
    while( buffer_pointer < strlen(buffer)){
        if(buffer[buffer_pointer] == 10){
            if(j==0){
               start = buffer_pointer+1;
               printf("headstart = %u\n",start);
            }
            else{
                printf("\n%u start = %u\n",j,start);
                end = buffer_pointer;
                amount = end - start;
                strncpy(data, buffer+start,amount);
                memcpy(info[j-1],data,strlen(data));//need help in this line
                printf("data = %s\n",info[j-1][20]);
                memset(data,0,20);
                start = end+1;
                printf("%u end = %u\n",j,end);
            }
            j++;
        }
        buffer_pointer++;
    }
}
```

When I execute above code , it gives following output instead of what I expected.

```
headstart = 13

1 start = 13
data = (null)
1 end = 18

2 start = 19
data = (null)
2 end = 21

3 start = 22
data = (null)
3 end = 34
```

Preferred output:

```
headstart = 13

1 start = 13
data = Udara
1 end = 18

2 start = 19
data = NO
2 end = 21

3 start = 22
data = +94123456789
3 end = 34
```

Comment: Note that there are cases when [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will not null-terminate the destination string. If that happens then using `strlen(data)` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: the prototype for a function that has no parameters: I.E. `void query_db();` should have a `void` between the parens.  Otherwise, the compiler will produce code that can take any number of parameters  Suggest the prototype be; `void query_db( void );`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: depending on which OS this is run on, this statement: `if(buffer[buffer_pointer] == 10){` might never be 'true'  Suggest using: `if(buffer[buffer_pointer] == '\n' ){`

Comment: regarding: `while( buffer_pointer < strlen(buffer)){`  the variable `buffer_pointer`, (which is actually an index into the buffer, not a pointer) is comparing a `int` with a `size_t`  (a `size_t` is a `long unsigned int`.   Your compiler should have told you about this problem

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis, like 20.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names via `#define` statements or a `enum` statement, then use those meaningful names through out the code

Comment: You might want to look at the function: `strtok()` as a much simpler method of breaking the string into individual segments

Comment: the expected output is failing to allow for the 1 (or two) characters of the instances of '\n' in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
memcpy((char *)&info[j-1],data,strlen(data));
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would suite this "answer" well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the wrong output is here:

```
printf("data = %s\n",info[j-1][20]);
```

You use the `"%s"` format to print a string, but `info[j-1][20]` is a single `char`. And it's out of bounds as well.

You probably meant to use `info[j-1]`.

Comment: And here: `strncpy(data, buffer+start,amount);`, it does not add a null char at the end.